# angularjs - How to inject generated javascript

Tags: angularjs

I have a angular js page, in which I get a javascript generated dynamically from backend. The content is as follows

```
<script type='text/javascript' language='JavaScript' src='https://secure.echosign.com/public/widget?f=XXX'></script>
```

My HTML

```
<div ng-bind-html="htmlString"></div>
```

My Controller

```
    $scope.init = function () {
        $scope.initForm({
            action: $attrs.action

        }, function (data) {
            $scope.htmlString = "<html><h3>so Here it is</h3>" + $scope.model.htmlScript + "</html>";
        });
    };
```

However when the page is rendered, the javascript tags are filtered out and the rest is displayed. Please suggest how I can proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular.js has a service called `$sce` ([Strict Contextual Escaping](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24sce)) which automatically uses `$sanitize` on directives like `ng-bind-html`.  If you wish to override the escaping, you need to hook into the `$sce` service and explicitly trust your strings.

**NOTE**

This is generally not a recommended method to handle arbitrary HTML that can come from non-trusted sources, as it can open your site up to exploits.

```
$scope.htmlString = $sce.trustAsHtml(
     "<html><h3>so Here it is</h3>" + $scope.model.htmlScript + "</html>");
```

Comment: thanks for pointers. Still I couldn't get it working. Following is the plunker URL http://plnkr.co/edit/vhOvLS0qrUxKmtNq4LUj?p=preview

Comment: I looked at the plunker, and I can see the script is emitted by document.write and is being retrieved by the server... without knowing what the script is I can't tell what else should happen?

Comment: were you wanting the HTML to be printed on the screen or were you wanting the script injected into your page?

Comment: the script is generated & provided by Adobe EchoSign through a REST API. All they provide is the following 

     <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"   src="https://secure.echosign.com/public/widget?f=8GM4H46Y5W7I26"></script>. 

To view it normally, I wrap it in html tags and I am able to see it in browser.

Comment: so I still fail to understand what is going wrong at this point.  Based on your plunker, you are using `ng-bind-html`, which inserts the string as inner html.  If you do not use `$sce`, nothing is emitted, as the script is not trusted.  If you do use `$sce`, the string is emitted, and the script is parsed.  If you actually want to print it out, then it prints when using `ng-bind`.

Comment: I know it is hard to comprehend, and I am in same boat. As you mentioned, if I use $sce, the javascript is emitted onto the html, but it is not effected. 

The javascript effectively contains a bunch of document.write statements, but it doesn't get rendered in the page. Compare the plunker output vs having the following code in a simple html page and open in browser

Comment: HTML snippet below

<html>
    <div>
    <p ng-bind-html="htmlString" class="ng-binding"><h3>so Here it       is</h3><script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="https://secure.echosign.com/public/widget?f=8GM4H46Y5W7I26">
    </script></p>
    </div>
    </html>

Comment: I don't really think you can do what you want to do with Angular.js, because javascript doesn't get parsed by the browser when it's inserted into the innerHTML.  Is there some reason that this script has to be injected by angular.js and can't just be put in the html independently?

Answer (score 0):

Is there anyway you can inject the JS with a script tag at startup?  I do some similar kinds of things where I create a URL that calls a django view and that views is returned as javascript.  In the html it looks like this:

```
<script src="app/generated.js"></script>
```

And I simply return a valid piece of javascript from the server.  Since it comes over as a script tag, the browser has no idea it was generated.  It's how I handle user specific customization.

In my django app, I return the response as content type 'application/javascript'

Given this kind of example, you could simply inject a `<script>` tag into the page at a later point.

**And the details:** (Since I don't know the platform you are using, I'll do it in django which I feel is very readable.)

In Django, you have functions that are mapped to urls like this:

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^generated.js$', generate_javascript, name="generate-custom-js")
```

This line will cause the function generate_javascript to run if that URL is requested from the server.  In that function, I authenticate the user, and lookup some things from the database. then I render the javascript for this customer via a template.

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def generate_javascript(request):
    previous_scores = Scores.objects.get(user=request.user).order_by('-date_recorded')[0:10]
    return render(request, 'generate.tpl.js', locals(), content_type='application/javascript')
```

Then you complete the template like this:

**generate.tpl.js**

```
var scores = [ 
{% for score in scores %}
     {{ score.number }}{% if not forloop.last %},{%endif %}
{% endfor %}
];
```

When rendered, this template generates a "file" that looks like:

```
var scores = [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5
];
```

It's not the prettiest javascript you'll ever write, but it will parse and the browser doesn't care what it looks like.

Then in your **index.html** you have a line like

```
<script src="generated.js"></script>
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example. I am unable to visualize your solution.